# Fetch joins returning more rows than they should

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, jpa-2.0, jpql

I have hit a strange problem with some joins I am doing. In a nutshell if I do a *left join* I get a correct number of rows. If I do a *left join fetch* I get more rows than expected.

My entity classes are (using pseudocode for brevity)

```
public class One {
   ...
   private Set<Two> twos;
}

public class Two {
   ...
   private Set<Three> threes;
}

public class Three {
   ...
}
```

In my relationship I have four *twos* in class *one* and nine *threes* in each class *two*

I was expecting to have returned one class one with four twos and in each of these twos nine threes.

I get this if I use

```
List<One> res = em.createQuery("select o from One o left join o.twos t left join t.threes where o.id = 322", One.class).getResultList();
List<Two> twos = resultList.get(0).getTwos(); //results in four twos - CORRECT

List<One> res = em.createQuery("select o from One o left join fetch o.twos t left join t.threes where o.id = 322", One.class).getResultList();
List<Two> twos = resultList.get(0).getTwos(); //results in four twos - CORRECT

List<One> res = em.createQuery("select o from One o left join fetch o.twos t left join fetch.threes where o.id = 322", One.class).getResultList();
List<Two> twos = resultList.get(0).getTwos(); //results in thirty size twos - *INCORRECT* (is four * nine)
```

Why does the second fetch cause it to multiply. I am having performance problems with my DB so want to do fetch joins to try and improve them. By doing the fetches though I seem to have lots more results than expected.

I am using Oracle XE as my DB and JPA2/hibernate as my ORM.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that the collections are Sets, and not Lists?

Comment: Do your classes `One`, `Two` and `Three` correctly implement `equals()` and `hashCode()`?

Comment: aha! Thanks JBNizet. I simplified this too much as the structure is a lot more complicated. When I went through it I found a spurious list which should have been a set! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As per comment from @JB Nizet I found a spurious List in my hierachy. To solve this you need to make sure that everything is using a set. If you have more than one list you will get JPA errors about *cannot fetch multiple bags*. If you have one list you wont but you end up with duplicates

Comment: That is a hibernate specific issue, not JPA.   See  https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-1718

Comment: Thank you.. Good Learning for me